# Shortcode style parsing

Tags: php, shortcode

Looking at how WP uses shortcodes I thoufght I could implement the same structure into a project, I assumed this would be availble somwehere but have yet to track down.

I started to parse myself starting with a preg_match_all 
`preg_match_all('/[[^]]*]/', $content, $match);`
and that return the array with all the shortcodes inside content as expected but then looking at parsing the name, variables or array keys with values I start getting real heavy on parsing.

My current thought is to break up on spaces, then parse each but then i run into spaces in the values even though they are in quotes.  So if i parse quoted data first then spaces to re-construct it seems very wasteful.  I don't need to re-invent the wheel here so any input is fantastic.

example

[shortcodename key1="this is a value" key2="34"]

would like to have

`Array
(
    [shortcodename] => Array
        (
            [key1] => this is a value
            [key2] => 34
        )`

)

here is the complete function that is working if anyone else is looking to do the same, obviously this is not meant to run user content but the called function should do any checks as this only replaces the shortcode if the funtction has a return value.

```
function processShortCodes($content){ // locate data inside [ ] and 
//process the output, place back into content and returns
preg_match_all('/\[[^\]]*\]/', $content, $match);
$regex = '~"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+~';
foreach ($match[0] as $key => $val){
  $valOrig = $val;  // keep uncleaned value to replace later
  $val = trim(substr($val, 1, -1));
  $replaced = preg_replace($regex,":",$val);
  $exploded = explode(':',$replaced);
  if (is_array($exploded)){
    $fcall = array();
    $fcallName = array_shift($exploded); // function name
    if (function_exists($fcallName)){ //  If function exsist then go
      foreach ($exploded as $aKey => $aVal){
        $arr = explode("=", $aVal);
        if (substr($arr[1], 0, 1) == '&'){
          $fCall[$arr[0]]=substr($arr[1], 6, -6); //  quotes can be &quot;
        }else{
          $fCall[$arr[0]]=substr($arr[1], 1, -1);
        }
      }
      if ( is_array($fCall) && $fcallName ){
        $replace = call_user_func($fcallName, $fCall);
        if ($replace){
          $content = str_replace($valOrig,$replace,$content);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to change all spaces not wrapped in quotes to let's say a semicolon then explode by semicolon

```
$regex = '~"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+~';
$subject = 'hola hola "pepsi cola" yay';
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,";",$subject);
$exploded = explode(';', $replaced);
```

[Credits](https://ideone.com/KeVBMj)

Comment: FYI - The use of semicolon in explode caused the explode to use spaces as well, not sure why but changing to a colon worked as desired.